# perform automatic html button from Java in Android

Tags: java, android

I am writing an App in Java Android. The App constantly communicates with contents in a Web Server. In the Server, I have an HTML file that has another button. I wish that When I press the button in my Android App, the button in the HTML file is auto clicked. Is it possible without using a webView?

Comment: you can do it by sending http request ( `POST`,  `GET` ) from your android application to your server side then you can perform your work

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am not the owner of this website, to send a request you need to know the API that is behind the HTML button.

Answer (score 0):

After a search I found that it can be done through 2 methods:
1- you can find the API behind the HTML button by right-clicking on the website>Inspect > click on your HTML page button and take the URL from the Network tab and in your program do HTTP get or post request.
2-this is the most efficient and valid method even if it is a dynamic url behind the HTML button, using the jsoup library.
first, look for the links on the HTML page and extract the one of your button then make an HTTP get or post request.
you can follow this code.

```
File input = new File("/tmp/input.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");

Element content = doc.getElementById("content");
Elements links = content.getElementsByTag("a");
for (Element link : links) {
  String linkHref = link.attr("href");
  String linkText = link.text();
}
```